# Render a Drupal node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-nodes, drupal-render

I would like to show a node inside another node. So I retrieve the node id of the second node and I would like to render/print/... it inside another node.
But I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried `drupal_render`, `node_view`, `print`,... but with no results. Any advice?

```
$nid = $node->field_linked_fiche['und'][0]['nid'];
$fullFiche = node_load($nid);
```

**EDIT - the whole template**

```
<?php

    /**
     * @file
     * Bartik's theme implementation to display a single Drupal page.
     *
     ...
     */
    ?>
    <div id="page-wrapper"><div id="page">

      <div id="header" class="<?php print $secondary_menu ? 'with-secondary-menu': 'without-secondary-menu'; ?>"><div class="section clearfix">

        <?php if ($logo): ?>
          <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" id="logo">
            <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
          </a>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($site_name || $site_slogan): ?>
          <div id="name-and-slogan"<?php if ($hide_site_name && $hide_site_slogan) { print ' class="element-invisible"'; } ?>>

            <?php if ($site_name): ?>
              <?php if ($title): ?>
                <div id="site-name"<?php if ($hide_site_name) { print ' class="element-invisible"'; } ?>>
                  <strong>
                    <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><span><?php print $site_name; ?></span></a>
                  </strong>
                </div>
              <?php else: /* Use h1 when the content title is empty */ ?>
                <h1 id="site-name"<?php if ($hide_site_name) { print ' class="element-invisible"'; } ?>>
                  <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><span><?php print $site_name; ?></span></a>
                </h1>
              <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($site_slogan): ?>
              <div id="site-slogan"<?php if ($hide_site_slogan) { print ' class="element-invisible"'; } ?>>
                <?php print $site_slogan; ?>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

          </div> <!-- /#name-and-slogan -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php print render($page['header']); ?>

        <?php if ($main_menu): ?>
          <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
            <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
              'links' => $main_menu,
              'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'main-menu-links',
                'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
              ),
              'heading' => array(
                'text' => t('Main menu'),
                'level' => 'h2',
                'class' => array('element-invisible'),
              ),
            )); ?>
          </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($secondary_menu): ?>
          <div id="secondary-menu" class="navigation">
            <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
              'links' => $secondary_menu,
              'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'secondary-menu-links',
                'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
              ),
              'heading' => array(
                'text' => t('Secondary menu'),
                'level' => 'h2',
                'class' => array('element-invisible'),
              ),
            )); ?>
          </div> <!-- /#secondary-menu -->
        <?php endif; ?>

      </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#header -->

      <?php if ($messages): ?>
        <div id="messages"><div class="section clearfix">
          <?php print $messages; ?>
        </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#messages -->
      <?php endif; ?>

      <div id="main-wrapper" class="clearfix"><div id="main" class="clearfix">

        <?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
          <div id="breadcrumb"><?php print $breadcrumb; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($page['sidebar_first']): ?>
          <div id="sidebar-first" class="column sidebar"><div class="section">
            <?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
          </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#sidebar-first -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div id="content" class="column"><div class="section">
          <?php if ($page['highlighted']): ?><div id="highlighted"><?php print render($page['highlighted']); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
          <a id="main-content"></a>
          <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
          <?php if ($title): ?>
            <h1 class="title" id="page-title">
              <?php print $title; ?>
            </h1>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
          <?php if ($tabs): ?>
            <div class="tabs">
              <?php print render($tabs); ?>
            </div>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
          <?php if ($action_links): ?>
            <ul class="action-links">
              <?php print render($action_links); ?>
            </ul>
          <?php endif; ?>
          // Render second node inside this one
          <?php 
              $nid = 739; // NOTE :: Hard coded, but need to be variable!!
              drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)))
          ?>
          <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
          <?php print $feed_icons; ?>

        </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#content -->

        <?php if ($page['sidebar_second']): ?>
          <div id="sidebar-second" class="column sidebar"><div class="section">
            <?php print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?>
          </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#sidebar-second -->
        <?php endif; ?>

      </div></div> <!-- /#main, /#main-wrapper -->

      <div id="footer-wrapper"><div class="section">

        <?php if ($page['footer']): ?>
          <div id="footer" class="clearfix">
            <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>
          </div> <!-- /#footer -->
        <?php endif; ?>

      </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#footer-wrapper -->

    </div></div> <!-- /#page, /#page-wrapper -->
```

Comment: I didn't test it but it should work with drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)))

Comment: No, I told you I already tried this...

Comment: I guess you did something wrong because I did the same thing ( `drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)))` ) to display multiple nodes on the same page and it worked perfectly.

Comment: And you did it in your page.tpl?

Comment: I'm curious how you did it... The script you just posted didn't do anything in my `page.tpl.php`. I get this error: `Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in include() (line 9 of ***`

Comment: Maybe a version mismatch? In Drupal 6, `node_view()` returns the themed node (i.e. it calls `drupal_render()` internally), so it gives already rendered and 'ready to use' markup. In Drupal 7, `node_view()` only prepares the structured array needed by `drupal_render()` to generate the markup.

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7. So which snippet do I need?

Comment: In Drupal 7, you'd need the snippet posted by Marius Ilie (`drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)))`). If it does not work for you, you should verify your preconditions and the in between steps, i.e. do you have a valid nid, does node_load() return a valid node object, etc...

Comment: I have a valid $nid (a `var_dump` shows me all the aspects of the node) and so does the `node_load()`. But I keep getting the variable error mentioned above...

Comment: I did it in a module, not in the page.tpl.php but the syntax should be the same. Also, I first loaded the node then render it: 
`$node2 = node_load_multiple($nids);`
`$output = drupal_render(node_view($node2));`

Comment: I just tried it, but I must be doing something terible wrong, cause still no results appear...

Comment: can I see the code you're using? I mean the whole template

Comment: It's just a standard `page.tpl.php`, with your code added...

Comment: you forgot to print the rendered content :)
<?php 
  $nid = 739; // NOTE :: Hard coded, but need to be variable!!
  **print** drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)))
?>

Comment: BTW, I flagged the deleted answer by Marius Ilie for moderator attention, requesting to revert the delete, as it looks like it was the correct answer. (I can see deleted answers, but can not undelete them myself).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
<?php
  $nid = 739; // NOTE :: Hard coded, but need to be variable!!
  print drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)));
?>
```

---

NOTE: Reposted, as original answer got deleted.

Comment: Added a note on the reposting to prevent moderator confusion ;)

Comment: It's better to use variable to avoid strict warning

Comment: This will lead to a strict warning: only variables should be passed by reference.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't test it but it should work with

```
drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)))
```

Comment: I guess you did something wrong because I did the same thing ( `drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)))` ) to display multiple nodes on the same page and it worked perfectly.

Comment: And you did it in your page.tpl?

Comment: I'm curious how you did it... The script you just posted didn't do anything in my `page.tpl.php`. I get this error: `Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in include() (line 9 of ***`

Comment: Maybe a version mismatch? In Drupal 6, `node_view()` returns the themed node (i.e. it calls `drupal_render()` internally), so it gives already rendered and 'ready to use' markup. In Drupal 7, `node_view()` only prepares the structured array needed by `drupal_render()` to generate the markup.

Comment: +1 to remove the undesired negative score (probably not worth bothering the moderator again for re-deletion ;)

Answer (score 5):

drupal 7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7

```
<?php //use variable to avoid strict warning
$nid = 739;
$nodeview = node_view(node_load($nid));
print drupal_render($nodeview);
?>
```