# How to use $node_load()

Tags: php, drupal

I'm new in drupal. My problem is that my content on the page doesn't appear. I would like to use `$node_load($nid)`. I know my `$nid`. I want to display my content by loading the node, but I don't know where to place and how to use it, in which template do I use it?

Comment: You should provide any existing examples that are not working.  It will go a long way in getting someone to assist you.

Comment: I add a field collection to basic page to make a slider. The title of the page appiers but the slider not.

Comment: This post may be use full. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564265/render-a-drupal-node

Comment: More info please. On what page are you trying to display node content? On that node page or somewhere else?